# Prevent Imperva CDN from showing origin IP info when we stop web site on IIS

Tags: https, cdn, iis7

I am using a CDN as proxy for my web site.
When i stop that web site on IIS & open web site in browser(without `https://`) default page of IIS shows like below:

[image: IIS 7]

CDN supports SSL.
For configure web site to work with SSL I did this on IIS:

[image: https]

Problem is when I stop web site in IIS & open `https://example.com` in browser default page of IIS does not show and the page below shows:

[image: Error 20 Of CDN]

How can i show default page of IIS when site is stop and we are trying to open web site with (`https://`)?

Comment: Why would you want to show the default page from IIS?  An error seems completely appropriate to me.

Comment: That error shows my server & proxy ips to others. I want to hide my ip because of hackers & spammers.

Comment: The right solution for that problem is changing the configuration at the CDN.  There are going to be times when it can't contact your server and shows this message. It isn't realistic to have 100% uptime at your server to prevent that.  What CDN are you using?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller My CDN is [imperva](https://imperva.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping your server up 100% of the time to prevent Imperva from showing that error page isn't realistic.  If you don't want that information shown, you need to change the page shown by the CDN.  Here is [Imperva's documentation for custom error pages](https://docs.imperva.com/bundle/cloud-application-security/page/error-pages.htm)

This is only one of eight error pages that Imperva may show.  You will probably want to create custom error pages for all eight possible errors.